# Why does my validationgroup not work?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, constraints

I have an entity which has a bunch of Approvals. All approvals are extended from a BaseApproval class, where I have defined a validation group:

```
abstract class BaseApproval {
    ...
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="textField", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"required"})
     */
    private $textField;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="approvedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"required"})
     */
    private $approvedAt;

}
```

For a proof of concept, I implemented in my ApprovalFormType the `setDefaultOptions` the default to:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
            return ['Default', 'required'];
        }
    ]);

}
```

In the entity, the approvas are added like so:

```
MyEntity {

    /**
     * @var HseApproval
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Hn\AssetDbBundle\Entity\Approvals\SomeApproval", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @Assert\Valid
     */

    private $someApproval;
}
```

Yet the validation is not triggered, the field is set as if all validation is disabled. Which is what I am trying to achieve, based on a condition only.

Comment: The actual class where you are storing the Approvals needs to extend the abstract class.  I'm not sure if you have an entity named BaseApproval, but you would need a line like this class Approval extend BaseApproval{...

Comment: @George The actual class is the extended class. SomeApproval extends BaseApproval. Found the typo in question, but was only relevant for the question not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that the BaseEntity also had a [callback validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 ...
 * @Assert\Callback(callback="validate")
 */

abstract class Approval
{
    ...

    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        // some logic messing with my AssertNotBlank constraints 
    }
}
```

I added what I wanted to do with the validation groups there as well. I suppose it should be possible to work with them as well.